# conda: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available

Tags: r, rstudio, conda

I am trying to install RStudio through conda, and bumps into this problem:

```
conda install rstudio
Solving environment: failed
- rstudio
- m2-openssh
- rstudio
- m2w64-diffutils
- rstudio
- m2w64-grep
- rstudio
- r-essentials[version='>=1.5.1']
...
```

its not just rstudio:

```
conda install r-base
Solving environment: failed
- r-base
- m2w64-bwidget
- r-base
- m2w64-bzip2
- r-base
- m2w64-fftw
- r-base
- m2w64-gcc-libs
- r-base
- m2w64-gmp
- r-base
- m2w64-gsl
- r-base
- m2w64-libiconv
- r-base
- m2w64-libjpeg-turbo
...
  Current channels:
- https://conda.anaconda.org/r/win-32
- https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch
```

It seems that everything prefixed by m2w64 is missing.

```
conda install m2w64-bzip2
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
...
conda info m2w64-bzip2
<nothing shows up.>
```

.. which is definitely not true.

Conda seems selectively blind at all those m2w64-* libraries in r channel. I am lost. How can I fix this ?

```
      conda version : 4.4.10
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.6.4.final.0
   base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
```

Comment: out of curiousity why install r-studio IDE through conda when you can install it directly?

Comment: What is the output of `conda config --show channels`?

Comment: @abhiieor I have multiple workstations to attend to. Miniconda makes setup easier on windows. All can be installed/updated properly with scripts without GUI interaction.

Comment: @darthbith, I was using mirror, turned out the `repodata.json` in their repo is not complete, though all `m2w64-*` packages already present in their directory.

Comment: @Ben So is it fixed now?

Comment: Yes, after adding official `msys2` or `defaults` into the channel list, it start to work.Since the link to official repo is very slow here, usually they are all commented out. I think the mirror is messed up, all these m2w64-* packages are not supposed to be in `pkg/r/win32` directory. but `msys2/win32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a json file in every conda repo directory, containing all package info. In my case, the error is directly related to that json file content.

I was using UCST repo mirror, and disabled official repo due to connectivity issues. After reenabling official repo, the error is gone.

Afterwards, by comparing the content of the mirror's json file and official repo's json file. It is clear the mirror's json file is messed up. so does the directory content. Not sure if UCST has fixed it or not.

That's it.